# How does modprobe.d blacklist work, exactly?

Tags: udev, modprobe

### Problem

I have conflicting drivers: `xpad` which comes standard with Arch, and [`xone`](https://github.com/medusalix/xone) which I installed from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xone-dkms-git). Both claim to support my Xbox One wireless controller even though only the `xone` driver knows what to do with it.

```
$ modprobe -R usb:v045Ep02F9d0114dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFisc5Dip01in00
xpad
xone_dongle
```

AFAIU, the culprit is the `alias: usb:v045Ep*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc5Dip01in*` in the `xpad` driver which is too inclusive.

I want only the `xone_dongle` loaded for the modalias above. But I don't want to disable the `xpad` driver completely, because I also use a wired Xbox 360 controller `usb:v045Ep028Ed0114dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFisc5Dip01in00` which I still want to be handled by `xpad`. I don't need them to work at the same time, but at least if I plug one of them after a clean boot, either should work.

### Attempted solution

The manual page for `modprobe.d` states:

> the `blacklist` keyword indicates that all of that particular module's internal aliases are to be ignored.

Which sounds like if I blacklist `xpad` and then define my own alias for it, it should work the way I want:

`/etc/modprobe.d/gamepad.conf`

```
blacklist xpad
alias usb:v045Ep028Ed0114dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFisc5Dip01in00 xpad
```

But instead it completely prevents the `xpad` driver from loading, even though the alias is correct.

Also, even though I've blacklisted `xpad` in the configuration, `modprobe -R` still finds it for the modalias of the wireless dongle.

### Non-conclusion

Can someone please shed some light on how this actually works? Is there a bug in `modprobe`? Is `modprobe.d` documentation incomplete? Which aspects of `modprobe` should be affected by the `modprobe.d` configuration and which shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

How `modprobe` work? `modprobe` load and unload the Linux modules with its **dependencies** automatically from any PATH. Followed by the `-v` option (verbosity) you can see what the `modprobe` do exactly.

In your case, you have to unload the Linux module through `modprobe -rv module` then you have to load the desired module without its dependencies using the `insmod` command.

Unlike `modprobe`, `insmod` doesn't check and load any dependencies if they exist.

To load a Linux module, you have to set the path to the kernel module:

```
sudo insmod /path/to/kernel_module.ko
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps me. When udev detects a new device, it runs modprobe with the device modalias as the parameter. In my case it's `modprobe usb:v045Ep028Ed0114dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFisc5Dip01in00` for the wired controller and `modprobe usb:v045Ep02F9d0114dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFisc5Dip01in00` for the wireless dongle. I want the former to load the `xpad` module and the latter to load the `xone_dongle` module. Can I achieve this with just modprobe configuration?